# The units digit of a perfect square is 6. What are the possible values of the tens digit?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, square-numbers

I know the answer to this already: the possible values of the tens digit are 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9. But I don't know how to prove it, can someone help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose
$$n=\sum_i a_i10^i$$
Then 
$$n^2\equiv 20a_1a_0+a_0^2\pmod{100}$$
Setting $a_0=6$, this becomes $20a_1+36$. With the choices of $a_1$ we obtain $1,3,5,7,9$ as desired.

Comment: $a_0=4$ is also possible, but doesn't change the answer.